# Managing group memberships in kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm administering a k8s cluster (on Google Kubernetes Engine if it matters) and would like to apply a fairly fine-grained RBAC role to all of our users that aren't service accounts.

From reading documentation, I gather that groups are a bit of a made-up construct in the sense that each user just has a list of strings attached to it specifying which groups it belongs to.

However, I can't figure out where this is actually kept track of. There's no such thing as `kubectl get groups`. It seems like k8s by design outsources the management of all this stuff to whatever system is doing the authentication/authorization, but I can't find how Google IAM is handling it either. Am I misunderstanding the whole thing?

Answer (score 2):

Since May 2019, it is possible to use [Google Groups membership in RBAC on GKE clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#google-groups-for-gke) within G Suite.  Please see the link for more details.

*Disclosure: I was a member of the Google team that implemented the feature.*

Answer (score 0):

The RBAC [feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#assigning_permissions_to_users_with_rolebinding) is not available on GKE for Google groups. You will have to use Cloud IAM in order to assign permissions to groups.